# c++ iterator vector struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iterator

I created a struct with two fields of type `Point3f` (which is inherited from another header).

```
struct C_Cell {

  Point3f min, max;

};
```

then I created a vector of `C_Cell`

`std::vector< C_Cell> grid;`

and I have filled through `grid.push_back(c)` where `c` is a `C_Cell`.

Now, when I try to iterate the vector, through

`for (std::vector<C_Cell>::iterator it = grid.begin() ; it != grid.end(); ++it)`

during debugging, the type of it isn't `C_Cell` but `Point3f`, which is the type of the field, moreover empty.

How can I iterate correctly, in such a way to obtain a single element of type `C_Cell`?

Thanks ( and sorry for my english! :) )

Comment: Your title is a collection of tags. Its pretty much worthless, and few people will bother with it since you did not take the time with your question. You should use the title to summarize your question or problem.

Comment: right... you have reason. sorry and thanks

Comment: First result in Google for my search "cpp vector iterator struct" though.

Answer (score 14):

You have to dereference the iterator and use it like

```
(*it).min
```

or

```
(*it).max
```

or, without de-referencing,

```
it->min
```

The type of the dereferenced iterator `(*it)` SHOULD be `C_Cell`, as that's how iterators work, their `operator*` returns a reference to an object of the underlying type of the container. Iterators behave very much like regular pointers (although they are not regular pointers, but proxy classes), you can increment/dereference etc.

Comment: yes, of course, but in debugging it->min result of type point3d.
in fact the object is empty.

Comment: @user3641602 `it->min` has the type `Point3f`, as you point inside the structure. My guess is that you don't initialize the structure before pushing it back into the vector. Make sure that before `push_back(c)`, `c` is an initialized structure.

Comment: @user3641602 then just try to post a minimal compilable example, from your code there is no way of saying what else could go wrong. Can you at least e.g. `cout << (it->min).member` lines inside the `for` and see what is being printed at runtime?