# Printing time_t in a vector struct member

Tags: c++

Sorry, I think this might be a silly question. While trying to use [ctime](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) to print a time_t inside a vector struct member, the compiler throws me this error `argument of type "time_t" is incompatible with parameter of type "const tm *"`

```
struct Trade_Record
{
    std::time_t PASP;
};

std::vector<Trade_Record> Trade_Records;


for (std::vector<Trade_Record>::iterator begin = Trade_Records.begin(); begin != Trade_Records.end(); begin++)
{
    std::cout << ctime(begin->PASP) << endl;
}
```

How could I print time_t inside a vector struct member? Thank youuu!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ iterator vector struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583945/c-iterator-vector-struct)

Comment: `const tm *`? This is impossible. You might use `asctime`.

Comment: @273K what exactly is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) on the matter:

> This function returns a pointer to static data and is not thread-safe. In addition, it modifies the static `std::tm` object which may be shared with `std::gmtime` and `std::localtime`. **POSIX marks this function obsolete and recommends [std::strftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead.**
> The behavior may be undefined for the values of `std::time_t` that result in the string longer than 25 characters (e.g. year 10000)

You should use `strftime` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    char mbstr[100];
    
    if (std::strftime(mbstr, sizeof(mbstr), "%A %c", std::localtime(&t))) {
        std::cout << mbstr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

> Tuesday Tue May 17 07:51:34 2022

([See online](https://godbolt.org/z/5WKaWzx1Y))

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```cpp
    std::cout << ctime(&begin->PASP) << std::endl;
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!! Could I further ask why a & should be added in front of the iterator? From what I learned from school, the vector iterator "begin" is a pointer. Therefore, what effect would it bring by adding & in front of "begin". Thank you so much!!

Comment: > From what I learned from school, the vector iterator "begin" is a pointer. Yes, it's a pointer, it points to the *first element* of the vector instead of pointing to the adress of `PASP`, you are accessing the first element with `begin->PASP`. Since the function signature of `ctime` is `char* ctime (const time_t * timer)`, it requires  the address of your `PASP`, `&a` gives address of `a`.